# How to bound input dimension for differential_evolution_minimize in tensorflow-probability?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

Unlike in [scipy's implementation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html) of differential evolution (DE), there is no direct way to define bounds for my inputs
in [tensorflow-probability](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/optimizer/differential_evolution_minimize).

Since the inputs to my function are 5-tuples defining a pixel in an image
(x,y,R,G,B), the values would need to be integers and bounded to my image dimension as well as RGB values of 0 to 255 during optimization.

To paint the bigger picture:
I want to minimize the confidence of an image classifier which itself is part of a reinforcement learning agent that needs to decide on an action depending on its observation of the environment. The agent is fully trained but now I want to throw a few stones by perturbing a single pixel in its observation and monitor its performance.

I want to use the differential evolution algorithm to find the pixel which would decrease the confidence of the agent in its actions the most.

Currently I have an action-prediction function, which takes as an argument the perturbation pixel, runs the perturbed observation through the classifier and returns the resulting confidence in the action which the agent would have chosen without the perturbation:

Code block I

```
#random perturbation pixel as an example of my input:
pixel = tf.constant([36,48,255,255,255]) # (x,y,R,G,B)

def predict_action(pixel):
   perturbed_obs = perturb_obs(pixel, observation)
   confidence = classifier(perturbed_obs)
   return confidence
```

Now I would want to give this function to the optimizer with an initial population:

Code block II

```
popsize=80

init_pop = generate_population(popsize)
# returns Tensor("scan/while/Squeeze:0", shape=(80, 5), dtype=int64)
# i.e. 80 random perturbation pixels

results = tfp.optimizer.differential_evolution_minimize(
    predict_action, initial_population=init_pop, seed=42)
```

Yet, how do I define the bounds of my input, such that the population will always be valid pixels?

I asked about this on [GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/issues/534) and a possible way of achieving this is through the use of their bijector functionality:

Code block III

```
# First we squash `pixel_logits` to (0, 1), then scale it to (0, 255).
bijector = tfb.Affine(scale=255.)(tfb.Sigmoid())

def unconstrained_objective_fn(pixel_logits):
    return objective_fn(bijector.forward(pixel_logits))

results = minimize(unconstrained_objective_fn, initial_position=bijector.inverse(initial_pixels))
pixels = bijector.forward(results.position)
```

While I understand the approach in principle, I fail to apply this to my current situation/understanding of my problem.

EDIT: Removed information that was unrelated to the main question. Always mind your types and dimensions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experience with tfp-0.6 and tf-1.13.1, Code block III could be rewritten as follows:

```
width = ... #some Python float
height = ... #some other Python float

bijectors = [
    tfb.Chain([tfb.AffineScalar(scale=width), tfb.Sigmoid()]),
    tfb.Chain([tfb.AffineScalar(scale=height), tfb.Sigmoid()]),
    tfb.Chain([tfb.AffineScalar(scale=255.), tfb.Sigmoid()]),
    tfb.Chain([tfb.AffineScalar(scale=255.), tfb.Sigmoid()]),
    tfb.Chain([tfb.AffineScalar(scale=255.), tfb.Sigmoid()])
  ]

def constrained_objective_fn(pixel_logits):
    constrained_pixel_logits = [b.forward(p) for b, p in zip(bijectors, pixel_logits)]
    return objective_fn(constrained_pixel_logits)

results = tfp.optimizer.differential_evolution_minimize(
constrained_objective_fn, 
initial_population=init_pop, 
seed=42)

pixels = [b.forward(p) for b, p in zip(bijectors, results.position)]
```

Note that the initial population from Code Block II is preserved and bijector.inverse is not applied.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it's pretty much the same as the bijector in Code Block III just without being fancy :) This definitely helps. Now I have to worry about the data types as the DE only accpets floats (as does tf.sigmoid) do you just sanitize your inputs in your objective function i.e. cast float inputs to integers?

Comment: To maybe be also of some help: It has been remarked on the GitHub post, that the sigmoid function does never actually return 0 or 1 (which makes sense mathematically), so if those are typical minimas in your application you might want to consider shifting your inputs by -0.5 while adding +1 to your bounds and then clip the values after the transformation. Otherwise getting pixels at the border or getting black or white as colors is almost impossible.

Comment: I still have some trouble with my code but I don't think it's due to your part which answered my initial question so I am gonna accept it as the solution. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @ninji I am interested in understanding and helping you solve your problem. Can you create a github repo and add foabodo as a contributor?

Comment: Separately, I am curious about @SiegeLord’s solution and plan to experiment with it. I understand the need to map from constrained to unconstrained space when using MCMC algorithms, but don’t think it is necessary for genetic algorithms used in discrete problems like yours. If I am wrong, hopefully a comparison between the results of the two approaches will reveal so.

Comment: I have edited my answer to incorporate @SiegeLord's Bijector-in-the-objective-function recommendation. The answer still excludes use of bijector.inverse since I think that could be causing your continued trouble. In my project, I have observed that when bijector.inverse is applied to the initial position, the objective function evaluates to infinity for every member of the population in the very first iteration, leading the algorithm to converge due to this equality and my program to terminate.

Comment: thanks for your willingness to help, I really appreciate it. As this project is part of ongoing research and also my master thesis, I will talk to my supervisors about disclosing the source code before publication. I since managed to resolve the issues and I am doing some sanity checks right now. I will get back to you.

Comment: @ninji if you think you are all set, then please disregard the source code comment.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a regular dtype error: you appear to be passing a `tf.int64` type into the initial position/population argument of differential evolution, while it expects (understandably) floating point tensors. Here's a version of your final code snippet that works for me:

```py
initial_pixels = 0.5

bijector = tfb.AffineScalar(scale=255.)(tfb.Sigmoid())

def objective_fn(pixels):
  return tf.square(pixels - 0.75)

def unconstrained_objective_fn(pixel_logits):
    return objective_fn(bijector.forward(pixel_logits))

results = tfp.optimizer.differential_evolution_minimize(unconstrained_objective_fn, initial_position=bijector.inverse(initial_pixels))
pixels = bijector.forward(results.position)
print(pixels)
```

Comment: Yes, I figured it out after reading through the code/docs of DE more closely. At this point It's just a matter of fixing my own code to match the requirements.

Comment: What I currently do not understand about your bijector solution:
Wouldn't the bijector scale all my dimensions to (0,255), including image size (which is 72x96 pixels)? In my mind I would need a bijector for x,y and RGB dimension each.

If you don't have the time, feel free to just tell me to read the documentation

Comment: If you're using two separate arguments for pixels and size, then yes, you can use two separate bijectors:

`def unconstrained_objective_fn(pixel_logits, size_logits): return objective_fn(pixel_bijector.forward(pixel_logits), size_bijector.forward(size_logits))`

If for whatever reason you're using a concatenated vector for both parameters then we have a `tfb.Blockwise` bijector which lets you apply different bijectors to different parts of your vector:

`overall_bijector = tfb.Blockwise([pixel_bijector, size_bijector], [num_pixel_dims, num_size_dims])`

Comment: I see. I think we were talking past each other a bit but I understand now how I would apply the bijector for my purpose. The argument I'm trying to optimize is both the location of the pixel inside the image and its RGB value respectively. I define
`x_bijector = tfb.AffineScalar(scale=95.)(tfb.Sigmoid())
y_bijector = tfb.AffineScalar(scale=71.)(tfb.Sigmoid())
RGB_bijector = tfb.AffineScalar(scale=255.)(tfb.Sigmoid())` and pass them seperately to my objective function. Thanks for your help!